# SQL modification to adjust depending on values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I insert some data from one table to another table. Just simple query with part i am intrested:

```
INSERT INTO column1value*100*column2value,
            column4value
...
```

How to make if column1value value is either NULL or empty SQL trade that as:

```
INSERT INTO 100*column2value,
            column4value
...
```

if column2value is either NULL or empty to be:

```
column1value*100
INSERT INTO 100*column2value,
            column4value
...
```

Comment: What is `INSERT INTO column1value*100*column2value` supposed to mean? That makes no sense. You should explain what you're trying to do, ideally with example input and output data.

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes no sense.  But the logic you want would seem to be `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(column1value, 1) * 100 * COALESCE(column2value, 1),
       column4value
```

You can use the same expression in a `VALUES()` clause.

Comment: so if column1value will be either NULL or empty it will calculate this correctly?: * 100 * COALESCE(column2value, 1) ?

Comment: @Arie . . . Apart from a `NULL` value, there is no such thing as an "empty" numeric column.

Comment: I do INSERT INTO .. SELECT there is no Values so means only Select statment has to be adjusted as you proposed.

Comment: what about if i would like to do if at least one variable is NULL to trade entire formula as NULL and not only specific parts. Is this possible?